# How do I bundle ts files into one index.d.ts file?

Tags: typescript

This is an example of what I want to build. Is something like this possible with the typescript compiler?

```
 * @namespace PIXI
 */
declare namespace PIXI {
    /**
     * String of the current PIXI version.
     *
     * @static
     * @constant
     * @memberof PIXI
     * @name VERSION
     * @type {string}
     */
    var VERSION: string;
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? The outFile option in tsconfig.json should allow you to achieve this.

Comment: This is what I've used to build a file: tsc --module amd and this is the outfile: "outFile": "./build/index.js". But I've got something completely different than that example and I don't know how to get that.